# Reading first row from a csv file with pipes-csv

Tags: csv, haskell, haskell-pipes

I am reading a csv file with pipes-csv library. I want to read first line and read the rest later. Unfortunately after Pipes.Prelude.head function returns. pipe is being closed somehow. Is there a way to read head of the csv first and read the rest later.

```
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import Pipes
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as P
import qualified System.IO as IO
import qualified Pipes.ByteString as PB
import qualified Data.Text as Text
import qualified Pipes.Csv as PCsv
import Control.Monad (forever)

showPipe :: Proxy () (Either String (V.Vector Text.Text)) () String IO b
showPipe = forever $ do
    x::(Either String (V.Vector Text.Text)) <- await
    yield $ show x


main :: IO ()
main = do
  IO.withFile "./test.csv"
              IO.ReadMode
              (\handle -> do
                  let producer = (PCsv.decode PCsv.NoHeader (PB.fromHandle handle))
                  headers <- P.head producer
                  putStrLn "Header"
                  putStrLn $ show headers
                  putStrLn $ "Rows"
                  runEffect ( producer>->
                              (showPipe) >->
                              P.stdoutLn)
               )
```

If we do not read the header first, we can read whole csv without any problem:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  IO.withFile "./test.csv"
              IO.ReadMode
              (\handle -> do
                  let producer = (PCsv.decode PCsv.NoHeader (PB.fromHandle handle))
                  putStrLn $ "Rows"
                  runEffect ( producer>->
                              (showPipe) >->
                              P.stdoutLn)
               )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Pipes.Csv` has material for handling headers, but I think that this question is really looking for a more sophisticated use of `Pipes.await` or else `Pipes.next`. First `next`:

```
>>> :t Pipes.next 
Pipes.next :: Monad m => Producer a m r -> m (Either r (a, Producer a m r))
```

`next` is the basic way of inspecting a producer. It is sort of like pattern matching on a list. With a list the two possibilities are `[]` and `x:xs` - here they are `Left ()` and `Right (headers, rows)`. The latter pair is what you are looking for. Of course an action (here in `IO`) is needed to get one's hands on it:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  handle <- IO.openFile  "./test.csv" IO.ReadMode
  let producer :: Producer (V.Vector Text.Text) IO ()
      producer = PCsv.decode PCsv.NoHeader (PB.fromHandle handle)  >-> P.concat
  e <- next producer
  case e of
    Left () -> putStrLn "No lines!"
    Right (headers, rows) -> do
      putStrLn "Header"
      print headers
      putStrLn $ "Rows"
      runEffect ( rows >-> P.print)
  IO.hClose handle
```

Since the `Either` values are distraction here, I eliminate `Left` values - the lines that don't parse - with `P.concat`

`next` does not act inside a pipeline, but directly on the `Producer`, which it treats as a sort of "effectful list" with a final return value at the end. The particular effect we got above can of course be achieved with `await`, which acts inside a pipeline. I can use it to intercept the first item that comes along in a pipeline, do some IO based on it, and then forward the remaining elements:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  handle <- IO.openFile  "./grades.csv" IO.ReadMode
  let producer :: Producer (V.Vector Text.Text) IO ()
      producer = PCsv.decode PCsv.NoHeader (PB.fromHandle handle)  >-> P.concat
      handleHeader :: Pipe (V.Vector Text.Text) (V.Vector Text.Text) IO ()
      handleHeader = do
        headers <- await  -- intercept first value
        liftIO $ do       -- use it for IO
          putStrLn "Header"
          print headers
          putStrLn $ "Rows"
        cat               -- pass along all later values
  runEffect (producer >-> handleHeader >-> P.print)
  IO.hClose handle
```

The difference is just that if `producer` is empty, I won't be able to declare this, as I do with `No lines!` in the previous program.

Note by the way that `showPipe` can be defined as `P.map show`, or simply as `P.show` (but with the specialized type you add.)

Comment: P.next was prefect solution for my case. Also thank you for showing map version of showPipe.

Comment: Also removing the Either with P.concat was really nice trick.